# Where does Drupal store information after creating a rule?

Tags: 7, database

I'm wondering where Drupal stores information in the database when one creates a rule with an event *A node has been flagged* and an action *Grant user points to a user*.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules are stored in the rules_rules table in D7. The table contains the rows of name (a machine readable name) and data (a data blob).

---

^ this is from D6, D7 has rules stored in rules_config, with rules_trigger holding the triggers and the ID of the rule and the trigger matching to each other.

Comment: I can't find a rules_rules table in my database... Did you mean rules_config?

Comment: No, rules_rules. You should have a rules_config, rules_dependencies, rules_rules, rules_sets, rules_tags and rules_trigger tables.

Comment: I don't have the rules_rules and rules_sets tables. Is that abnormal?

Comment: Are you able to create rules and save them?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do so.

Comment: Actually, I was looking at rules 1.x from D6. My bad. 

Looking at the schema for D7 in the rules.install file (good place to look at how a module is setting up it's database tables) there should be a rules_config, rules_trigger, rules_tags and rules_dependancies. 

The trigger, ie "after a node has been flagged" or published, or what have you, will be in rules_trigger, it's ID matches the id of a rule in rules_config.

Sorry about the mixup.